# Joining two tables using Include() with conditional filter

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-6

I have existing code to update. I want to join another table called `Table3`.
Since the query has an *include* to `Table2`, I want to add another `.Include` with a conditional filter and avoid a left join.

When I add the `.include` with the `.where`, I can't access `t3Id`. Intellisense just shows the table, `Table3` and not the `Id` field.

Did I miss a syntax? Thanks.

`Table1` has a key called `t1Id`.

```
 var query = (from e in ctx.Table1
    .Include(r => r.Table2.Select(p => p.name))
    .Include(rj => rj.Table3).Where(s => s.t1Id == t3Id)
    select e).ToList();
```

**`Table1` will have the following:**

```
Id  name  
1   Joe   
2   Mary
3   Harry
```

**`Table3` will have the following:**

```
t1Id   title
3      staff
3      fulltime
```

**Expected Outcome:**

```
1  Joe
2  Mary
3  Harry  [{2, staff}, {3, fulltime}]
```

Since Harry has a record in the mapping table, he will have an array of `Table3` rows.

Comment: is the where clause supposed to be for `rj.Table3`

Comment: After the error, I don't think so. I trying to figure out how to figure the Table3 where t1Id == t3Id and return all the T3 data for each T1 row.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking for. Can you show me a basic example data set of table 1, table 2, and table 3 and the expected outcome you are looking for?

Comment: HI Train, Just added the table illustration

Comment: using .net 4.7 and entity framework 6.3.0

Comment: if you have another suggestion on how to filter the ids. I can't change the EF version. so far, I can't access the id on the second table to do a .where( s => s.t1id == r.t3Id). I am wondering if I got the syntax incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I'll take a look as soon as I get some more free time.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: You can't avoid a left join with Include. I also wonder about the first `Include`. What's `Select(p => p.name)` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use `Select` instead of `Include` whenever you can. `Select` will allow you to query only the properties you really plan to use, making the transfer of the selected data from the database management system to your process faster.

For instance, if you query "Schools with their Students", ever `Student` will have a foreign key with a value equal to the School's primary key. So if you have School 10, you'll now that all its 5000 Students will have a `SchoolId` with a value 10. It is a bit of a waste to send this same value 10 over 5000 times.

> When querying data, always use Select. Only use Include if you plan to update the fetched data.

Your query (in method syntax):

```
var result = dbContext.Table1
    .Where(table1Element => ...)    // only if you don't want all elements of Table1 
    .Select(table1Element => new
    {
         // only select the table1 elements that you plan to use:
         Id = table1Element.Id,
         Name = table1Element.Name,

         // Select the items that you want from Table 2:
         Table2Items = table1Element.Table2
                       .Where(table2Element => ...) // only if you don't want all table2 elements
                       .Select(table2Element => new
                       {
                            // Select only the properties of table2 you plan to use:
                            Id = table2Element.Id,
                            Name = table2Element.Name,
                            ...

                            // the following not needed, you already know the value:
                            // Table1Id = table2Element.table1Id, // foreign key
                       })
                       .ToList(),

         // Table3: your new code:
         Table3Items = table1Element.Table3
                       .Select(table3Element => new
                       {
                            // again: only the properties you plan to use
                            Id = table3Element.Id,
                            ...

                            // the following not needed, you already know the value:
                            // Table1Id = table3Element.table1Id, // foreign key
                       })
                       .ToList(),
    });
```

You see that it is much easier for the reader to see which properties he gets? If one of the tables is expanded, then the new properties are not fetched in this query, after all: the user apparently didn't need the new properties. They are also not described in the specifications of this function.

Note: Because I used `new`, my types were anonymous types. You can only use them within your function. If you need to return the fetched data, put the data in a known class:

```
.Select(table1Element => new Table1Class()
{
    Id = table1Element.Id,
    Name = table1Element.Name,
    ...
});
```

Again: consider not to fill the foreign keys, as you probably won't use them

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed your EF comment. The EF property `Table1.Table3` should already load the related entities without using a where clause when you use the include.

Try this extension method

```
    public static IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAllIncluding(this params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includesProperties)
    {
         return includesProperties.Aggregate<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>,
         IQueryable<TEntity>>(_dbSet, (current, includeProperty)
         => current.Include(includeProperty));
    }
```

To use the function

```
 var data = table1.GetAllIncluding(x => x.Table2, y => y.Table3);
```

This should already load the related entities without having to filter.